# GeoTIFF Conversion

Tags: gdal, netcdf, geotiff

I've seen several requests like this but I still have one pressing question...

GDAL is often suggested as the easiest way to convert GeoTIFF files into a different format. I downloaded several GeoTIFF files from the FAA website. The downloaded raster maps are compressed zip files which, when extracted, contain 3 files:  a .TIF, a geospatial .tfw and .htm metadata file.

The GDAL command to convert the input.tif to a NetCDF output.nc is:
`gdal_translate -of NetCDF <input filename> <output filename>`

How does GDAL create a georeferenced NetCDF file from the .tif input file only when the geospatial data is in a different .tfw file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If no georeferencing information is available in the TIFF file itself,
> GDAL will also check for, and use an ESRI world file with the
> extension .tfw, .tifw/.tiffw or .wld, as well as a MapInfo .tab file.

https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to work with `xarray` and/or `rasterio` in python. Very easy way to safe GeoTiff as a netcdf file.

[xarray.open_rasterio](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_rasterio.html)